# How to exclude a word pattern without using a flag with egrep in Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to exclude the word 'ford' from the following text which is in the file named 'cars.txt', BUT the catch here is that I can't use any flag(the obvious one would here be -v). Just regular expressions within quotes.

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500
chevy   nova    79      60      3000
ford    mustang 65      45      17000
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
ford    ltd     83      15      10500
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    thundbd 84      10      17000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
chevy   impala  65      85      1550
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

I tried `egrep "^[ford]" ./cars.txt` but it finds all the 'ford' keywords and not exclude them! I shuffled all the websites regarding this, but no luck!

Comment: If it was obvious, I wouldn't have asked @JeelPatel! Thank you for removing the invalid tag. Now, please tell us specifically why this has to be the deprecated `egrep`, as opposed to `grep`, and why the use of options/flags is disallowed. The only reasons I can think of, is that this is not a real world scenario, but a challenge for yourself, which you're expecting somebody else to achieve for you.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how regular expression work, you can refer to the online [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html).
To catch all the lines except the one beginning with "ford", you can match all the possible brands followed by a blank (meaning of "[[:blank:]]") except "ford" at the beginning of the line (meaning of "^"):

```bash
$ egrep "^(plym|chevy|volvo|Chevy|fiat|honda|toyota)[[:blank:]]" cars.txt 
plym    fury    77      73      2500
chevy   nova    79      60      3000
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
chevy   impala  65      85      1550
```